Static Routing - Send all unresolved traffic to another IP
I'm not 100% when it comes to configuring switches and I have a requirement to send any requests for things outside of the network onto a specific IP address. I know how to add static routes I just don't know how to configure it in this instance.
I have an "air gapped" network. All DNS resolution is internal as there is no external access however a link has been fitted to accommodate very specific purpose which I can't detail. I need to send all requests not within our network to this link (firewall). I have the IP to send the requests to but I don't know the format for capturing requests we can't fulfill. Hopefully that makes sense?
Any assistance would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That sounds like the complete opposite of "air gapped".

I don't know the format for capturing requests we can't fulfill.

Any route that is "larger" than your actual network will work this way, because overlapping routes are ordered by their specificity – more-specific (smaller) routes will have priority, while less-specific (larger) routes will take what remains.
So if you want to route everything that your existing routes don't already cover, you would use a /0 route, 0.0.0.0/0 also known as a "default route".
